# cat does not seem to work inside a bash cgi script

Tags: bash, cgi, cat

Example to reproduce this problem:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo Content-type: text/html
echo
echo "<html>"
echo "<head>"
echo "<title>"
echo "Test-A"
echo "</title>"
echo "</head>"
echo "<body>"
echo "AAA"
cat <<EOS
test A0
EOS
echo "</body>"
echo "</html>"
exit 0
```

When running this script through the browser, the browser shows the title as "Test-A" and the body as AAA, but the string *test A0*, which is supposed to be produced by `cat`, is not present.

For debugging, I also added a few silly statements such as

```
echo BBB|cat
echo CCC|/bin/cat
```

but neither *BBB* nor *CCC* show up. This is weird: After all, `cat` just writes to stdout and this should be collected like with `echo`. Other programs run fine: If I do a `ls -l /bin/cat`, I do see the output, which shows as

> -rwxr-x--- 1 _apt nagios 43744 Feb 28 2019 /bin/cat

Needless to say, that even a

```
cat SOME_FILE
```

does not produce any visible output in the returned page either.
Any idea why cat does not work here?

There are no error message (such as command not found) in the error logs. Hence I believe that my script does not write anything on stderr. Also, `cat` is present as we not only see from the output of `ls`, but also that a `type -a cat` displays its location (`bin/cat`).

The bash on this server is GNU bash, version 5.0.3 (as shown by `bash --version`, but I can not identify any version for `cat`, because `cat --version` does not produce any output either.

**UPDATE:**

Trying out a few other commands, I found that - for instance - the output of `ruby --version` shows up in the returned webpage, while the output of `uname` does not. Hence, `cat` is not the only command which behaves strangely. `uname` does as well. I don't see, what they have in common, but is different from commands such as `ls` or `ruby`.

Comment: The ownership and permissions on your `/bin/cat` look a bit odd - remember your CGI script runs as the lowly `_www` user. Try also setting the `PATH` explicitly at the top of your script. Good luck!

Comment: PATH is OK (otherwise `type` would not identify the command correctly).Good point about the permissions. I will check it, whether they are also wrong for `uname`, and contact the hosting company to change this. I'm just surprised that I did not see any error message in the logs.

Comment: Some details about CGI? It can be interactive terminal problem or incorrect output too.

Comment: @lojza: While it would be weird if a CGI script is executed by as an *interactive* shell, as you suspected, I don't see how this could explain the behaviour I see. However, I had tested this aspect too in the beginning, by doing a `echo $-` (I did not include this information in my posting, as I considered it irrelevant). Further, I don't see what you mean by _incorrect output_; you see my small test script. Nothing incorrect in the `cat` use. Actually, even a `cat --version` or a `echo FOO|cat` did not produce any output.